# Assigning current user in rest framework view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been getting my head around these basics but I am not getting it right. I am trying to associate my view to my user model using team which is a foreign key. When I try to create of a gps, I get an error saying "team is a required field" but instead it should be read only. The team attribute should be filled automatically with the id of the currentUser

**Model**

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)

class Gps(models.Model):        
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False)
    team= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializers**

```
class GpsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gps
        fields = ('id','location','team')
```

**view**

```
class Gps_list(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Gps.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GpsSerializer
    team = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, 
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
```

Comment: I think team should go into `GpsSerializer` instead of the view. Could you also remove `read_only=True` ?

Comment: I get this error thrown `Relational field must provide a queryset argument`

Comment: Maybe adding `queryset=User.objects.all()`could help  instead of readonly? That is required in DRF 3.x

Comment: It is still throwing the same error. I can't really tell if i have been through the right procedure

Comment: I also highly recommend using `Team` for your model name instead of `User` as because django also use the same name. Unless you are changing the built-in model, makes sense to distinguish that.

Comment: Are you logged in? If that only works when logged-in then you can force view to require authentication as in [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

Comment: I am not logged in yet. According to the doc http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/  this is what i am following. I couldn't see any login authentication

Comment: Oh I look like I answered already, current user is for django's built-in model, not for your model :) Therefore, serializers.CurrentUserDefault() won't bring it. You will have to assign it manually or use `contrib.auth.models.User`. You should change your Gps model to use django's User model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two changes needed. First, `team` field definition should be moved to serializer class instead of view. Second, you should use Django's `contrib.auth.User` model instead of your definition of User, as because `serializers.CurrentUserDefault()` will bring `request.user` only. So you should remove your User definition and import that to your `models.py`:

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Further steps would be to replace `read_only=True` with `queryset=User.objects.all()` to allow create.

Comment: In this case, it is always best to use Django's user model?

Comment: Yes, that is well supported. For your needs later on, you can still extend and replace it as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user), but you can also create another class, say `Profile` and handle extra fields there.